# Stance on "Is X a better language for poetry?" questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions

I'm wondering what the general opinion on questions like these is. I've came across a couple of so far, and personally i don't think they belong on linguistics SE. The tone of the question tends to be polemical, and it's generally impossible to give an objective answer. Here's a particularly ridiculous example: [Are Slavic languages better suited for poetry?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3988/are-slavic-languages-better-suited-for-poetry)
The accepted answer, despite being downvoted multiple times, endorses the questioner's contention that slavic is a better language for poetry. It's fairly clear that the questioner had already decided on the answer before asking the question.

Do we want to get rid of obviously polemical and frankly unanswerable questions, or should we leave them up for people to see? I don't think it reflects brilliantly on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Close. I don't see any reason not to and have cast my vote accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with you that they're primarily asking for opinions and even if the OP tried to make it as objective as possible, it's something we cannot really measure.

I'll be closing this one. I'd like to say one thing:

Whenever you (or any other user) see questions like this, you can **flag and/or vote to close**. This last one is very important because it helps us moderators see what questions the community doesn't want. Remember that the community as a whole shapes the site, so don't just wait for us moderators to close. We will close clear-cut cases but we need the community to work with us! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure closing such questions is always the best option. I personally think that, regarding the Slavic languages and poetry question, an argument can be made that rich case inflections encourage flexible word order, which in turn makes it easier to arrange words according to the meter you desire and that at least makes it easier to write poetry. I feel that something like this was behind the question (or was I reading too much into it?), and it seems to be a valid linguistic argument. I didn't join the discussion because it was so polemical, and the way the question was phrased certainly wasn't ideal.

Perhaps we could come up with ways to encourage posters to phrase such questions in a more neutral manner, amenable to discussion? If posters don't follow the advice, the question can still be closed.